How to estimate if a mainstream media house is trying to promote a political agenda?
How can we judge that a mainstream media house is trying to promote a certain political agenda on behalf of a certain group? Can you give me some checkpoints?

What media house, mainstream or not, is not trying to promote a certain agenda on behalf of a certain group? I can't think of one Even the Weather Channel is trying to promote an agenda, which in their case is doing a better job of weather forecasting than other media. Media houses need eyes in the case of print & TV, or ears in the case of radio lest they lose money hand over fist. And that means filtering the info they present.

@DavidHammen I think they mean a political agenda, because that's what this site is about.

@Barmar I specifically chose the Weather Channel as an apolitical media house. Whether it's Fox News, CNN, MSNBC, Sunday morning shows such as Meet The Press, the New York Times, etc., they all have an agenda: More eyes and ears = better paying commercials and/or more subscribers. Get more of those eyes and ears! But do not antagonize the base audience of said organization. Every media organization knows their base audience.

@DavidHammen But a business agenda is not necessarily the same as a political agenda. "doing a better job of weather forecasting" is not political. OTOH, if they advocate related to climate change, that could be considered political.

@Barmar I do remember during the first Trump presidency when he butted heads with weather forecasters over what states a hurricane would or wouldn't hit which does sound political to me.

@Barmar A business agenda isn't necessarily a political agenda, but it might nonetheless be politically relevant. Like when Fox spread Trump propaganda despite the newscasters being on public record arguing how stupid and despicable they think that is and how much they hate it, but money is money.

@Barmar When Marjorie Taylor Greene, among others, state that storms are geo-engineered, then weather forecasting is put into a political light. How can the Weather Channel insist on hurricanes being predicable when it is ignoring the political posture held by national players?

@DavidHammen - I'm laughing at the idea that the Weather channel is apolitical. Certainly, the bit where they tell you what the weather is like outside your window is just about neutral, but it's immediately followed about commentary about political failure, climate change, water policy, etc etc.

Q: How do you tell they're pumping propaganda? A: Their lips are moving!

@DavidHammen You just don't know the story. Broadcasters had laws passed to ban NWS from disseminating over any broadcast media. Their argument is taxpayer funding is unfair competition. The counterargument is taxpayers pay for weather forecasting and are prohibited from receiving it in normal media, without somebody inserting ads or TV subscription fess.

There are two separate questions here: dishonesty and having a political agenda. While they are not unrelated, it is important to note that many organizations can and do promote an agenda while showing low levels of dishonesty, merely by being selective about what they do. E.g. if a South African newspaper always publishes a story whenever a White farmer dies, but rarely or never publishes stories about Black people killed in townships, that promotes a certain agenda as surely as if they made everything up, even if the stories are all true.
With that said, the standard method to judge the honesty of an outlet is fact checking. There are countless fact-checking organizations, such as Snopes or FactCheck, and many news outlets will have their own fact-checking wings. Obviously, some of the fact-checkers themselves have agendas, and some can even be dishonest, so one inevitably runs into the problem of who watches the watchers. At the very least, though, they do help to expose the most obvious lies or misrepresentations, and if an outlet publishes a lot of them, then they likely are doing so to promote an agenda (but their absence need not mean the absence of an agenda!)
By contrast, it's a little harder to measure the agenda of an outlet, and a little more fraught, precisely because it is hard to know how much it influences their journalism. From the most basic standpoint, any news outlet with an editorial section has an agenda, which is usually quite open and easy to see; of course, this is a little unsatisfying, because what we really want to know is to what extent that agenda leaks into their reporting. As with the fact checkers, there are sites that are dedicated to looking for bias in reporting, but they also have their limitations: what an American site considers a left-wing bias may not be the same as what a Portuguese site considers as such, let alone what a North Korean or Saudi Arabian site does.
This is also something that can be particularly salient with science, given the number of political orientations that tend to adopt their own interpretations of inconvenient truths. For instance, on a typical media bias tracking site, an article acknowledging the risks of global warming based on scientific evidence is likely to be considered politically entirely neutral, but right-wing audiences are likely to see it as having a left-wing bias from the beginning. And of course, they can suffer from the same problem as the fact-checkers or the news outlets themselves: their own honesty cannot be guaranteed from within.
Ultimately, the best way to be aware of whether media are promoting an agenda, dishonestly or otherwise, is to pay attention to as many outlets as possible, because outlets with opposing biases will usually leap on the chance to point out mistakes, omissions, slanted reporting or outright lies in the journalism of outlets that they are opposed to—and to treat those accusations with equal skepticism.

Folks, please do not make my answer your forum for discussing specific news outlets you believe are or are not biased. I think it's safe to say that there is at least one news outlet I could name has each of the various kinds of bias that you mention, but I don't want the comments underneath my answer to turn into a list of every news organization that may or may not have an agenda.

One of the key lessons I learned from my undergrad is that you cant MAKE someone believe something, only present some info and hope for the best, or worst. The media isn't like a syringe that just injects ideas into your head its always mediated by the culture and learnings of the reader/viewer.
So with that in mind I would simply note that all speech has an agenda, even mine, and even yours. That agenda might be "truth" but the truth in politics can be a slippery beast, and you can lie with the truth. Let me give a slightly confected example.
Lets imagine I'm a journalist and theres a politician I dislike and I really want to slime him. I also know that he's an asthmatic with poor control over it and as such is constantly honking on an asthma puffer. I could write a story claiming that he is a "drug abuser" and it would be technically true. He is abusing a drug, ventolin. But in your mind you might have the impression of the politician hiding in his office shooting heroin. I told a lie using the truth.
It really comes down to how words are used. The media and politicians love slippery illdefined words. Take "Woke". Its an old word used by some members of the african american community to denote that the person understand structural racism. But certain media talking heads have taken it and given it a whole new set of meanings and then accusing people of adhering to it.
Think about how this works. If I accuse someone of being woke because they support gay rights, and I've stretched my definition of "woke" to include that, well its not lying, that person really does support gay rights. But in peoples heads it then ties it to all the other definitions of "woke" that include things like "thinks cat litter boxes should be in classrooms for trans-cat children to defacate in" or "thinks antifa supersoldiers should round up all the white people" or whatever nutty thing has been added to the word this week. Its meaningless that almost nobody in the left identifies as "woke" or believes in whatever the silly things have been added to it, the point is to tell a big lie by attaching it to a small truth. The left have their own versions of this too, of course.
So thats my advice, understand that everyone has an agenda, and there really is no such thing as unbiased or balanced media (Balanced is a whole different nonsense term again. Should medical information be "balanced" with medical disinformation? Of course not. Sometimes there really is an objective truth.) but you can at least take a critical reading approach by looking at heated words and asking yourself "who defined this word, and what interest is being served by this definition".

Medical information isn't necessarily an "objective truth" nothing in science is, but usually it's not balanced with disinformation but with uncertainty, so with information on exceptions and side effects that could happen and how often they were reported. But yeah "balanced", "neutral", "moderate/center/middle" can be tricky terms depending on what people are talking about.

Another thing is that you can also have these kinds of word bending in "positive" directions as well. So technically right wing refers to ideals of hierarchical social structures and caste systems (formal or informal) so those folks after the French Revolution who wanted the aristocracy back and placed themselves on the right side of parliament. So those in favor or not averse to social hierarchies and inequality would be right wing. Meaning conservatives in the U.S. sometimes outright promoting social darwinism fit the term, however instead rather like to associate it with "freedom" instead.

The problem with how med-sci is presented is imho more to do with peoples innability to judge expertise. I'm not a doctor, some of my friends are, but I'm not. I do however know that I'm not an expert so if I want to find something out about it, I'll seek out someone who is, or an info source that is academically reliable (PubMed, Medsci stackexchange, cochrane reviews, Wikipedia but with some caution). Many people dont seem to do that though, and trust the judgement of .... youtubers? their facebook friend? etc. Failure to identify expertise correctly.

An almost shocking recent example was the disinformation around covid vaccines. A very large po rtion of people, though not a majority by a long shot, now believe its "accepted" that the covid vaccines where untested and dangerous. In reality the vaccines have ones of the cleanest safety records and underwent some of the most comprehensive testing in medical history. But both the public and media seemed completely unable to judge expertise and quack charlatans got to spread nonsense all over the internet with disastrous consequences.

A major problem that is often overlooked is also the discrepancy of data that normal people and med-sci people have access to. So essentially an individual has only themselves for direct benchmark and the people in their environment for indirect comparison. While science can access medical records of billions of people world wide. So suppose you are the only one with a problem in your vicinity you could be 1/10, 1/100, 1/1000 aso. So treatment could be standard or entirely unknown and you couldn't judge from your vantage point. Similarly what works for you might not work for other aso

Hence the need to recognize expertise. I dont have the ability to know whats good medical facts. But I do have the common sense to get on the phone and ask my doctor friend. I know I'm often out of my depth in certain problems at work, but I usually know who at work is an expert in a particular domain that I can take a problem  to..  Alas many fail to identify who is an authoritive source and will go youtubes shoutier tinfoil corners for medical advice or whatever.


How can we judge that a mainstream media house is trying to promote a certain agenda

Well by the fact that they DO promote a certain agenda. Like if being subtle would work in terms of advertisement, why would ads be trying to give me eye- and ear-cancer?
Also as Obie2.0 has mentioned there's a difference between a bias and dishonesty. Everyone has biases and often enough outlets aren't necessarily subtle about them. Which is to an extend ok. Like idk even if you dream of a world where people life in peace, don't kill each other or the planet, take care of each other and whatever more or less uncontroversial ideas, those would still be biases. For example when "helping each other", comes to the point where you actually need to do or not do something, then this means that stance is going to lead you to take a side for or against something.
What is much less ok is dishonesty, partisanship and covert(!) activism. That is, you don't just give your reasons to support something, but omit shortcoming of those proposals, omit serious alternatives and their advantages and shortcomings, misrepresent the situation or the alternatives.
The thing is if an outlet does a good job with regards to representing the facts, it might even be useful if you don't agree with its conclusions. While if the articles are poorly researched, unreliable and more pushing than informing about an issue, it might even be useless even if you agree with it.
So cross reading several biased outlets only really works if they all have a high standard of journalistic integrity! If they don't, then they aren't really useful for debunking either.
Now with regards to promoting an agenda on behalf of a person or group, rather than just having a slight bias towards a general direction. Well first of all you might want to check the available meta data.
For example media cross-ownership in the U.S. seems to be huge, so many outlets belong to the same parent companies and media conglomerates or some of those are even majority owned by private individuals (Rupert Murdoch (Fox Corp and News Corp) or the Sinclair Family (lots of local tv news) might come to mind).
So just checking the owners, authors, cross-ownerships, the revenue and employee figures and stuff like that, might, in some cases, already give you a hint on what to expect.
Also might want to look up how the non-covert things look like: activism, lobbyism, ... So if the reporting looks similar to that, well ... as said if it's the promotion of something it's usually not the secret very secret.
Classic things to look for might also be what the ads actually advertise for and whether there's a "separation of church and state", so a separation between editorial commentary, between advertisement and activism and between well research pieces and news stories or whether they blur into each other into "infomercials" or whatnot.
Similarly you might want to check the biases of their sources and whom they quote, who's featured as guessed editors and whatnot. Like usually there's already a lot you can read from the metadata.
Now whether they are actually linked to someone and directly doing their bidding is probably way harder to establish and would require other outlets with deeper pockets and/or law enforcement. But you might already smell the fish before you see it, so if it sounds like promotion and furthers a certain agenda, that's usually enough to be concerned about even if that person isn't directly involved.

I am not convinced this separation between "church and state" is possible for any media outlet.

Well then they shouldn't exist and I don't mean that in the sense of banning them but in the sense of that it is the responsibility of the readers to not honor them with their attention (and money) if they deliver subpar journalism.

The general rule is that if it easy to determine the personal views of those presenting the news about  political issues then  that media source   is trying to promote a political agenda.
In the world of journalism, objectivity or impartiality is considered a fundamental principle. Journalists are expected to report the facts, present multiple perspectives, and remain unbiased in their coverage. A publication that fails in that regard  is trying to promote a political agenda.

There's no such thing as objectivity or unbiased reporting.

As several others, this answer seems to imply that if it's not easy for a random observer to determine the personal views, then the source is unbiased. Ironically, someone who's not a random observer can detect the answer's political bias merely by noticing how it praises "journalists" and their supposed adherence to this principle (which in reality exists only in fairy tales).

There is no such thing as objective or unbiased reporting.  If someone claims to be "fair and balanced", chances are that they're lying or at least deluded.  Possibly facts can be reported seemingly objectively (an objective truth does exist), but the selection of facts cannot, nor the priorities in investigative journalism.  Everybody has an agenda, consciously or subconsciously.  And corporate-owned media serve the interests of the owners; see how Mr. Bezos blocked the Washington Post publishing a pro-Harris editorial in the runup to the 2024 United States Presidential Elections.  Whether this was due to political preferences or for fear of his other businesses being penalised by a Trump presidency or yet another motivation, it shows the non-independence of the newspaper.
Likewise, when a local newspaper reports on a crime, there is really no objective way to determine what characteristics of the suspect are relevant (such as immigration status, religion, ethnicity), and either the inclusion or the omission of this information can lead to accusations of political bias.
What does exist is honesty.  Putting the cards on the table.  Who are the owners?  Who are the journalists?  What principles do they use to select what news to report on?  What guides their priorities in investigative journalism?  Many journalists keep blogs where they report on their work.  Some newspapers have sections showing what happens behind the scenes.  Others are cooperative owned and invite member-owners (or even all readers) to talk to the journalists and have a look behind the scenes.
My impression is that corporate-owned media are less honest than public media and that both are less honest than independent media.  But even independent media can still never be objective or unbiased.

This is one of the better answers here, but it is, in the end, just as far in la-la land as worse answers. No, NPR is far more dishonest than a random private media in USA, same with BBC in UK. They are incredibly, radically partisan. And honesty can also be incredibly misleading. For one, what does "Mexican Billionair owns NYT" tell you? Nothing. Heck, Bezos is left leaning, or at least was before 2020. Secondly, what has more effect is what the views of editors/publishers are (and journalists).

... Lastly, even if you take some really good drugs and pretend that they will actually be honest about all this (as opposed to claiming to be unbiased like they ALL do), including who every employee votes for and their honest political views; they wouldn't be able to report on their unconscious bias.

... plus, principles and priorities are at best vaguely stated ("newsworthy" is a really neat weasel word; and "have a source" sounds nice but doesn't mention that the source could have their own axe to grind, for ideological or even other reasons); and at worst unknowable - even the 100% honest unbiased reporter will end up basically intuitively choosing what to report on because they have finite time/money/info space for publishing; and they have no way to know how their intuition turns the art of choosing the story into reality of what gets published

@user4012 The BBC News website lost my trust due to their sensationalism and Brexit bias, essentially never covering the perspective of (then) three million EU citizens in the UK.  Other BBC programmes vary (Newsnight was not bad when I lived in England).  I'm not familiar with NPR.  When I lived in Canada I watched Democracy Now!, as my search for independent Canadian outlets was inconclusive; in Germany I read the taz and alternate between public ARD and ZDF for TV news, where ARD are more conservative and ZDF more progressive.

@user4012 Quite possibly Bezos has leftist views (I wouldn't know), and he blocked the Harris editorial fearing Trump would penalise Blue Origin.  That's arguably even worse (self-censorship fearing government power).  As for centrist or even centre-left media outlets; those will exist in a free market as long as people want to read it, but they're not independent and might get into a conflict if reporting on misbehaviour by a business owned by the same billionaire owning the newspaper.

It's interesting that the BBC seems to be accused of left-wing bias about as often as it's accused of right-wing bias…  (I think it suffers a bit from trying too hard to include ‘balance’ when the truth is clearly on one side; and some of the web pages seem aimed at a slightly shallower level than much of the broadcasting.  But to me it still seems one of fairer and more honest sources.)

@gidds Compared to the rest of the British media landscape, they're certainly better than most (it's hard to do worse than Daily Mail, Daily Express, News of the World, Daily Star).  But my impression is that during my time in England (2015-2019), the BBC News website turned more populist and quality degraded overall.

@gerrit I think that impression's fair for some pages, unfortunately.  But others (particularly the longer ones) are deeper and ask a bit more of the reader.  And there are many radio and TV programmes which have not dumbed down at all.

One rule of thumb that I use is:
If a news organization uses a lot of emotionally charged words, then they are likely to be biased.  In this case, they are not simply reporting the facts.

Ironically, this statement itself is highly misleading. In a very meta way. It doesn't mention important other bias ways, such as simply omitting inconvinient information, which are actually FAR FAR more insidious and thus effective, precisely because they pretend to be unbiased and do NOT come with an easy detection algorithm.

As others said, everyone has an agenda. Just accept that as an axiom. The question is, how much bias do they show?
There are some useable way to find evidence of bias:

Sentiment analysis. If you run the analysis and the media outlet uses negative language for candidate X 80% of time and for candidate Y 10% of time, they are likely biased. These days it's easier to do automatically by an algorithm.

Of course... who watches the watcher? e.g. who designs the algorithm/training-data-for-AI/ etc...? For example, the algorithm may consider "squirrelism" to be a neutral word but anyone knows that accusing people of squirrelism is a dog whistle for Hamburger party (and accusations are usually spacious).


Compare the outlet's bias to population at large. Maybe candidate X is really so awful as to legitimately in unbiased way warrant 80% negative sentiment? BUT... if the electorate as a whole has a breakdown of 50/50 or 55/45, clearly the outlet's bias is far different from the populace. That's a sign of biased coverage.
Somewhat similar to the last point - look at how both sides evaluate the outlet. If one side thinks the outlet is "fair and balanced" and the other side thinks the outlet is completely against them, it's a sign that the outlet is, indeed, biased to the first side. If the outlet is equally liked/hated by both sides, THEN it's likely less biased.
Fact checking by the opposite side. This is important. As another answer noted, maybe Snopes does exist, but maybe they have their own bias. So how do we resolve this dilemma? We allow the opposition to fact check. So, if candidate X's side makes a claim and candidate Y's side doesn't refute it, we can consider that claim "more truthy" than a claim that Y's side tries to debunk. Obviously both sides debunking is biased and not necessarily true; BUT, on average, you can gauge the bias of news outlet by comparing to this level of overall debunking.

Please note that bias does not even have be conscious to exist. As another answer said, the choice of what to cover and give limited coverage space, is a subjective choice by publishers/editors/journalists. And the bias is VERY VERY often in what they omit rather than what they cover, even if they try to use neutral language and (ha ha) we pretend that they are trying to be unbiased. I can give you 1000s of examples of mainstream media omitting - as a trend or individual cases - stories that would promote right wing side or prop up their arguments, only giving space to left wing side ones. Often, very possibly, simply because the journalist/editor being left wing, those are the stories that pique their interest/are judged important.
And in some cases, the bias is kind of built into reality. For example, you can - regardless of the political bias of the source - easily find stories that highlight "person X killed by a gun", which can be used to bolster pro-gun-prohibition side. However, you can't easily (or often at all) - even if you legitimately try - find many stories that help pro-second-amendment side, which would highlight "person Y didn't die or fall victim to another violent crime, because person Z chose not to attack them for fear they have a gun" or "person Y used their weapon to either defend from, or just scare off, an attacker". First, you can't easily prove a negative or a counterfactual in the first scenario. Second, even in more obvious cases (self defense in second scenario) a gun owner is less likely to report the altercation to authorities/news, for fear of getting into trouble or just hassle; and authorities don't bother compiling this as a statistics. I am sure left wingers can offer examples of this phenomena which hampers their side of the debate as well - important part is the principle of the fact that one side is easier to prove than another even if you try to be unbiased; not the specific topic.

In addition to "person X killed by a gun", some might report "person X killed by an immigrant" or "by an illegal immigrant" or "by a homeless person" or "by an anarchist" or "by a rich kid" or "by a muslim" or "by a jew" or "by a mexican".  Choosing what characteristics of the suspect/perpetrator are relevant to report is very difficult and I don't see how that can ever be objective, as either including or omitting the information are likely to face accusation of politically motivated reporting.

@gerrit - agreed (I was trying to keep the answer short, but this is definitely a great example)

Frame shift
Let's walk the question back to a more historical, more neutral format.
"How to estimate if a mainstream media house is trying to promote siding with a political agenda view?"
Even before the words "mainstream" and "agenda" got woven into this kind of question, it was by far the norm that even balanced media outlets would tend to some form of side-taking.

The Economist - economically liberal, pro free-market, anti-hard-left
Liberation (France) - working class left
Le Monde (France) - intellectual left
Figaro (France) - center right
National Post (Canada) - center right
...

I don't think this ha changed all that much, except maybe in America where polarization seems to be a marketing/audience retention strategy of sorts.  CNN evolved from relative neutrality, to strongly anti-Republicans stance.  Now, maybe, they'll move a more balanced coverage with their new CEO from a year or so ago (the quality of their coverage slipped as well, moving from onsite reporting to talking-heading).  Fox's raison d'etre is bias.
The outlets that did not take any sides, and indeed had a stated policy of neutrality, often had their own, commercial reasons, for remaining neutral, such as Reuters or AP which resell their content to smaller news outlets.
Another dimension affecting the news outlets nowadays is that what they are covering is more extreme, so they would naturally tend to "take sides" a bit more than previously.  Not-making-a-decision is sometimes making-a-decision when you don't call things out.  Neither Trump, nor Sarah Wagenknecht would have been considered serious, electable, politicians 40 years ago (a much more crisis-prone period when there was really hard persistent inflation and the specter of nuclear war).
That's why for example the Washington's Post refusal to endorse a candidate was badly received.
Basically, expect almost any media outlet to have some sort of bias.  Instead, be on the lookout for the quality of their coverage.  If you are really wanting to get information in a neutral way, try alternating between relatively low-bias/high-credibility sources covering the news from either side's perspective.
